# ArcGIS WPF Base map and other maps

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

We currently have a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application that is using the WPF runtime SDK to display and handle base maps and data maps. By default we always place the base map at the very back of the map control. The issue we are encountering is the base map has grids like (township etc.) but when other map service are added (for polylines and polygons) the grid names and lines are overlapped with it but we need to be able to see the grid names and lines. We have tried updating the polygon's transparency but it still overlaps the base map.

My question is, if there are any other way to handle the transparency between map services?

Worst case scenario is that we have to publish both the base map data and other data in to one map service and handle the transparency through the layers.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out. The solution was pretty simple. Each ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer has a "Opacity" property that we bind to a slider and now we can control the whole ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer transparency instead of just the individual layers.